# Как отобразить файловую систему в ListView - Программирование Android

Tags: java, android, файлы, listview

Здравствуйте! Делаю приложение под android и мне нужно показать файловую систему с возможностью перехода по папкам (нажимая на них). Потом пользователь выбирает файлы и они отправляются на сервер. Попробовал сделать, но везде, кроме папки с программой, говорит, что там нет файлов или папок (хотя они там есть, проверял), разрешения все поставил.
Заранее спасибо! Надеюсь, на Вас, так как мало времени осталось до сдачи проекта.

Все мои permission в AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Вот код:

```
    private String path;
    //...
    private void RefreshList(){
            File directory = new File(path);
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            Log.e("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);

            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (File file : files)
                arrayList.add(file.getName());

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
            ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_files)).setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    //...
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case android.R.id.home:
                    // Проверка... Если path - пустой, то переход к предыдущей активности
                    path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")); // Получение пути предыдущей директории
                    Log.e("Files", "Path: " + path);
                    RefreshList();
            }
            return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
        }
```

Comment: А на каком версии Android вы это делаете?

Comment: а где инициализируется и что содержит `String path`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо проблема в том, что вы используете Android начиная с 6 версии. Там уже по другому permissions выдаются. В вашем случае это должно быть примерно так:

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Так всё работает!

Comment: @Edward1406 знакомые грабли :)